# There is no content in Windows navigation side bar and appears to be loading

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

There are numerous users (at least 6 that I know of) that are having trouble getting their files to show on the navigation sidebar in Windows folder. It only displays favorites, libraries, and computer, with nothing dropped down. Even clicking will not navigate anywhere. Any ideas? I rebooted, several times, performed virus scans, uninstalled updates, installed updates, and system restore.

Here is a link to the screenshot, since I can't post images yet.

[image]

The problem seem to come and go, at random, rebooting will work, but the issue comes back a few minutes later.

Comment: Open Command Prompt as an Administrator & run regsvr32 /i shdocvw

see if it helps

Comment: no, that did not help.

Comment: Is this computer added do a Domain ? do you have network drives mapped ?

Comment: Yes, all of them are domain PCs with network drives mapped through logon scripts.

Comment: Use **NET USE** command to see mapped drives and then delete them using **NET USE X: /DELETE** See if it makes any difference !

Comment: ok thanks, i will try once  issue occurs again, like i said, it happens randomly. you think the network drives are causing the issue with not loading any content? including data located on the C drive?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26160/discussion-between-the-it-guy-you-dont-like-and-onlytito).